# Do thread-safe has relation with consistency in destructed system?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, distributed-system

These days I quickly studied some things about distributed system. I found multi-threads looks like a distributed system. (There are many cores in CPU and each core has its own cache.) What's more, I found there are many different of consistency (Linearizability，Sequential Consistency) in distributed system. If we see thread-safe structural as a distributed system, what consistency does it supports?